# Electric Field vs Electric Field Intensity

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

In my 1st year Physics college course, Electric Field at a point is defined as $\vec E = \frac {\vec F}q $. However, during high school, it was defined as

> An electric field is a region of space where a Coulomb force acts on a charged body placed in that region.

And Electric Field Intensity was defined as

> Electric field intensity at a point in an electric field is the force per unit charge acting on a test charge at that point

The definition for **electric field** I am learning now seems to be what was previously defined as the **electric field intensity**.

My question is, what is the difference then between a field, and the intensity/strength of the field, and how can we define a field generally?

Comment: You were taught correctly at high school. Your college lecturer is abbreviating "Electric field strength" (or "Electric intensity") to "Electric field". It's not a huge sin, though.

Answer (score -1):

A electric field is a vector which can exert forces to electric charges. Electric field intensity is always defined over a surface and if you calculate the surface integral of the E field for some surface you will get the electric flux.